# Formula added to embedded chart in Powerpoint with VBA is referencing wrong cells

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, powerpoint-2007

I'm updating charts in `Powerpoint 2007` from queries in `Access 2007`.
The charts have been manually added and set up using *Insert ~ Object ~ Microsoft Office Excel Chart* and should look like this (I've obfuscated the axis labels):
[image]

#### The problem

My Access query returns the data for the selected months, but I then need to add two extra series for the blank spaces between the months.

Currently I place the data in the worksheet, insert blank lines and use a formula to calculate the maximum value for the month, add 2 and minus the raw data value for that month.
An example of the formula is:  `=MAX(R3C2:R3C17)+2-R3C`.
If I step through my code this formula is entered correctly, but if I run the code it appears as `=MAX(R3C2:R3C17)+2-R3C[-1]` (converted in to A1 style in the sheet) and my chart appears as:
[image]
I did try updating the code so the final `C` is `C[+1]` and this worked for a little while (but I'm not happy with that as it shouldn't work and I don't know why it does).

The line of code that adds the formula is:

```
    .Range(.cells(x, 2), .cells(x, oLastCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=MAX(R" & x - 1 & "C2:R" & x - 1 & "C" & oLastCell.Column & ")+2-R" & x - 1 & "C"
```

As you can see I'm using `x-1` rather than `R[-1]` in the formula as `R[-1]` was returning row 65536 even though the formula is placed in row 3.

The data behind the chart appears like this (you can see where the formula is mucked up an returning an error value as it's trying to reference column A).
[image]

#### The solution I'm looking for:

How to get the formula into the worksheet correctly
(can't believe I'm asking that after starting on Excel 97).
or combining a cross-tab query with calculated data to perform the same function as the formula.
(I'll add the SQL and explain if anyone thinks that would be a better option).

The code to produce the report is below (the code is in Access).

**Code entry point:**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private sReportMonth As String          'Text displaying current month.
Private sReportYear As String           'Text displaying current year.

Public Sub Produce_Report()
    Dim sTemplate As String             'Path to PPTX Template.
    Dim oPPT As Object                  'Reference to PPT application.
    Dim oPresentation As Object         'Reference to opened presentation.
    Dim oSlide As Object                'Reference to slide in PPT.
    
    sTemplate = CurrentProject.Path & "\PPT Template\Reported Errors Template.pptx"
    
    Set oPPT = CreatePPT
    Set oPresentation = oPPT.Presentations.Open(sTemplate)
    sReportMonth = Forms!frm_CreateReport!lstMonths.Column(1)
    sReportYear = Forms!frm_CreateReport!txtYear
    
    'Add the month and year to the Title slide.
    Set oSlide = oPresentation.slides(1)
    With oSlide
        .Shapes("Report_Date").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sReportMonth & " " & sReportYear
    End With
    Set oSlide = Nothing
    
    Error_Trends oPresentation.slides(2)
    Error_Origin oPresentation.slides(4)
    
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'These two procedures produce the chart errors. '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Error_Categories oPresentation.slides(5)
    TeamBreakdown oPresentation.slides(6)
    
    MsgBox "Complete"
    
End Sub
```

**TeamBreakdown code:**
(Error_Categories is the same - I'll be combining once I know what's going on).

```
Private Sub TeamBreakdown(oSlide As Object)
    Dim oWrkSht As Object
    Dim oWrkCht As Object
    Dim oLastCell As Object
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim x As Long
    Dim itm As Variant
    
    With oSlide
        With .Shapes("chtTeamBreakdown")
            Set oWrkSht = .oleformat.Object.worksheets(1)
            Set oWrkCht = .oleformat.Object.Charts(1)
        End With
    End With
    
    Set oLastCell = LastCell(oWrkSht)
    With oWrkSht
        .Range(.cells(1, 1), oLastCell).ClearContents
    End With
    
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("SQL_REPORT_LSCTeamBreakdown")
    For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
        prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
    Next prm
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
    
    x = 2
    With rst
        'Place the headings first.
        For Each itm In .Fields
            oWrkSht.cells(1, itm.CollectionIndex + 1) = itm.Name
        Next itm
        .MoveFirst
        'Place the values.
        Do While Not .EOF
            For Each itm In .Fields
                oWrkSht.cells(x, itm.CollectionIndex + 1) = itm.Value
            Next itm
            x = x + 1
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    Set oLastCell = LastCell(oWrkSht)
    
    With oWrkSht
        'Add spacer rows to the raw data (equal to the maximum value in the row above plus 2 minus the value directly above).
        For x = oLastCell.row To 3 Step -1
            .Rows(x).Insert Shift:=-4121, CopyOrigin:=0  '-4121 = xlDown, 0 = xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            .Range(.cells(x, 2), .cells(x, oLastCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=MAX(R" & x - 1 & "C2:R" & x - 1 & "C" & oLastCell.Column & ")+2-R" & x - 1 & "C"
'Next line produces =MAX($B65536:$P65536)+2-A$2 (when entered in B3).
'            .Range(.cells(x, 2), .cells(x, oLastCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = _
'                "=MAX(R[-1]C2:R[-1]C" & oLastCell.Column & ")+2-R" & x - 1 & "C"
        Next x
        Set oLastCell = LastCell(oWrkSht)
        
        oWrkCht.SetSourceData .Range(.cells(1, 1), oLastCell), 1 'xlByRows
    End With
    
    RefreshChart oSlide.Application, 6, oSlide.Shapes("chtTeamBreakdown")

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set oWrkSht = Nothing
    Set oWrkCht = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Code to find last cell (as its used in the formula):**

```
Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Object, Optional col As Long = 0) As Object

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    With wrkSht
        If col = 0 Then
            lLastCol = .cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column
            lLastRow = .cells.Find("*", , , , 1, 2).row
        Else
            lLastCol = .cells.Find("*", , , , 2, 2).Column
            lLastRow = .Columns(col).Find("*", , , , 2, 2).row
        End If
        
        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1
        
        Set LastCell = wrkSht.cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer, but not the accepted answer as it's a workaround.

My original code used a formula to calculate the value needed for the spacer series - this kept placing an incorrect formula:

```
        'Add spacer rows to the raw data (equal to the maximum value in the row above plus 2 minus the value directly above).
        For x = oLastCell.row To 3 Step -1
            .Rows(x).Insert Shift:=-4121, CopyOrigin:=0  '-4121 = xlDown, 0 = xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            .Range(.cells(x, 2), .cells(x, oLastCell.Column)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=MAX(R" & x - 1 & "C2:R" & x - 1 & "C" & oLastCell.Column & ")+2-R" & x - 1 & "C"
        Next x
```

My workaround solution is to calculate the maximum value using `WorkSheetFunction.Max()` and then calculating the value that should be in each cell.

**Note:**  I have to use `oWrkSht.Parent.Parent.Worksheetfunction` to get to the Excel application instance used within Powerpoint.

```
    'Add spacer rows to the raw data (equal to the maximum value in the row above plus 2 minus the value directly above).
    For x = oLastCell.row To 3 Step -1
        .Rows(x).Insert Shift:=-4121, CopyOrigin:=0  '-4121 = xlDown, 0 = xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        'Return the maximum value in the row.
        Set rRange = .range(.cells(x - 1, 2), .cells(x - 1, oLastCell.Column))
        lMaxVal = oWrkSht.Parent.Parent.worksheetfunction.max(rRange) + 2

        'Calculate the value for each spacer cell.
        For y = 2 To oLastCell.Column
            .cells(x, y) = lMaxVal - .cells(x - 1, y)
        Next y
    Next x
```

This works, but feels like cheating....